# Return the nth record from MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am looking to return the 2nd, or 3rd, or 4th record from a MySQL query (based on a query by ID ascending)

The problem being, I won't know the ID, only that it is the 3rd row in the query.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT n-1,1`

It says return one record starting at record n.

Comment: I have changed it n,1 to n-1,1 because offset starts in limit from 0 not 1..as  this is an accepted answer so provide correct details to users.

Answer (score 38):

The accepted answer was wrong by 1 before the edit, because the **offset is zero-indexed**.

From the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
> first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
> rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

So the correct query would be

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT n-1,1
```

Answer (score 10):

for example "LIMIT 10, 5", it will skip the number of records indicated by the first number and then show the number of records indicated by the second number. In other words it's "LIMIT skip, show".

```
SELECT * FROM tblTesting LIMIT 3, 6
```

will display from 4th record to 9th record, total records displayed 6

if you want show descending order use `DESC`

```
SELECT * FROM tblTesting ORDER BY column_name DESC LIMIT 3, 6
```

Comment: better explanation of the answer (at least it made more sense to me in this context).

Answer (score 6):

Use the limit clause (add 'limit 3, 1' to the end of your query to only select the third row).

Here's some more information: http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: It would be limit 2, 1 because it's 0 indexed.

Answer (score 4):

MYSQL: The offset always start from zero-indexed

> OFFSET value means not start from OFFSET value
>
> Example: records 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
>
> OFFSET 1 means return 2nd value, as OFFSET 2 return 3rd value and so on

```
SELECT table_column FROM Table GROUP BY table_column DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT table_column FROM Table GROUP BY table_column DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 1;
```

*It will return 3 records from 2nd record*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP to process your records, then you might use the expressions from the PHP manual:

```
<?php
/* Open a connection */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY Name";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* seek to row no. 400 */
    mysqli_data_seek($result, 399);

    /* fetch row */
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    printf ("City: %s  Countrycode: %s\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

    /* free result set*/
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Read more in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php