# find the 5th row in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL/MySQL Workbench, and if I want to select the 5th returned row order by studentName, what is the solution? Thanks.

```
select * from Students order by studentName;
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return the nth record from MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224951/return-the-nth-record-from-mysql-query)

Comment: Smart solution, thanks Andy!

Comment: Does sound like homework though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT` in following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
ORDER BY Id 
LIMIT 4,1 -- here you provide which row you want to retrieve
          -- 4 indicates from which row start selecting (offset)
          -- 1 - how many rows you want to retrieve
          -- you can change It as you like
```

Comment: it should be limit 4,1.