# How to pass a variable to MySQL's LIMIT clause?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to make a SELECT statement to Mysql datbase using pymysql.
This is the code. I am passing a variable to the select statement, and to my surprise this is a huge pain in the lemon. Any idea what am I missing here?

```
def getUrlFromDatabase(n):
    stmt = "SELECT * FROM jsonTes ORDER BY website LIMIT %s-1,1"
    cur.execute(stmt,str(n))
    return cur.fetchone()

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='passwd', db='email_database', charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("USE database")

getUrlFromDatabase(0)
```

Error:

This is what I try to achieve: [Return the nth record from MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224951/return-the-nth-record-from-mysql-query)

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0'-1,1' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT` in MySQL takes numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants. You have to calculate the expression in Python and then pass the integer as a single parameter. Also, you need to put the parameter in a tuple:

```
def getUrlFromDatabase(n):
    stmt = "SELECT * FROM jsonTes ORDER BY website LIMIT %s, 1"
    cur.execute(stmt, (n-1 if n > 0 else 0,))
    return cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I tried your code, but I am still getting an error : pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-1, 1' at line 1")

Comment: Still getting an error :D pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-1, 1' at line 1")

Comment: The argument should be *nonnegative*. Try the update.

Comment: "LIMIT in MySQL takes numeric arguments, which must both be __nonnegative__ integer "

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the value 1 for %s in the string format.
`stmt = "SELECT * FROM jsonTes ORDER BY website LIMIT %s" %n` for limit n

Comment: It's not string formatting, it's a dbapi SQL query placeholder. The value is to be passed (with the query) to `cursor.execute()` and will be properly sanitized to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: But the error was `right syntax to use near ''0'-1,1'`. But if you can format it as a string and execute, won't it work? Without passing additional argument in execute however. @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: The error was that the OP passed a string (instead of a tuple with a single int) as argument to `execute()`. And yes doing it with string formatting _would_ work here (technically), but it's a huge security issue :  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Got the issue! But I do not think that's a security risk. Can you elaborate? @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Anything that might allow SQL injection is a security issue. Might not be that much of an issue with this particular case (and even then I wouldn't bet my users base on it), but given how many newbies are not aware of this problem advising simple string formatting here is doing them a great disservice.

Comment: Thanks, @brunodesthuilliers. I myself a Cybersecurity Masters graduate. and I do not think it matters in this case as you mentioned anyway. Just was curious what other security risks might this be prone to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131620/discussion-between-dhishan-and-bruno-desthuilliers).

Answer (score 0):

you can use like that

```
def getUrlFromDatabase(n):
    stmt = "SELECT * FROM jsonTes ORDER BY website LIMIT {}, 1"
    cur.execute(stmt.format(n-1 if n > 0 else n))
    return cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. Getting an error saying: pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-1, 1' at line 1")

Comment: can you provide the detail what limit you want to put here?

Comment: n will cycle from 0 to 1000. I started with 0.