# Convert A Relational Schema to SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I am currently taking Database Systems course in University this is a question from one of the exercises ,given by my instructor, that I couldn't figure out. I was able to do other questions. Thanks in advance.(primary keys are in italic)

QUESTION// 
Consider the following relational schema.

student(*sid*, sname, address, city, gpa)

course(*cid*, cname, iid)

enroll(*sid, cid*, grade)

instructor(*iid*, iname)

Give the corresponding SQL queries for each of the following.

- Find the id and name of the student with the 10th highest gpa. You can assume, for simplicity, that the gpa values are distinct.

Comment: What have you tried? its not a homework site. Have a go and people will help

Comment: Yes I know. I couldn't figure out how to get the 10th highest grade part. My main problem is there. Once I get the Idea writing SQL is not an issue.

Comment: Derived Table/Subquery/Inline view; whatever you want to call a query in the from clause that has an alias which limits by 10 order by GPA DESC.  Then an outer query that orders by GPA again ASC but limits by 1.  or you could Simulate a "Row_number()' analytic using user variables  "read up on those by searching for mySQL simulate row_number()"which would give you precise control over which row to return.  also must use a derived table.

Comment: Can I use 9 sub queries that delete the tuple with max gpa from the initial table therefore ın the last query ı can get the max gpa which will be the student with the 10th max gpa.  OR is there a simpler way?

Comment: You don't want to delete the data, you just want to select the data.  So yes there is a simplier way.  `Select * from tbl order by gpa desc limit 10` would give you a dataset of the students with the 10 highest grades.  Now with that set what could you do to get only the 10th?  You can also use offset to return the right row: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224951/return-the-nth-record-from-mysql-query  Read [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) Look for LIMIT and offset.

Comment: If you do some research to understand sub-queries then the most straightforward way to do this would be to take a top(1) or limit from another limited query ordered by value.

Comment: @RossBush  Yes originally I was going down that path but forgot about the offset function of limit which makes this VERY easy.  From docs: With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1): and `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15`

Comment: @xQbert As important as those shortcuts are, you can't take them everywhere. They certainly do make our lives easy everyday. That being said, understanding and working with sub-queries has taught me more than understanding the nuances of any single dialect of sql.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  It's the trial and failure and trying again which teaches us the most.  But asking questions and learing to read the documentation is just as important in my mind.

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking.  Do you want us to do all your homework?

Comment: Your google search string is `MySQL rank`.

Answer (score 0):

The psedocode I would attempt is select the top ten students with their gpa in descending order.  At that point you have ten GPA's in desc (greatest to least) order.  The 10th is at the bottom.  But how do you get the 10th?  You could subquery the result of that query, to get the top value in ascending (least to greatest) order.

A general way to subquery:

```
SELECT dT.Col1 
  FROM (
         SELECT Col1
           FROM Table
          --ORDER BY?
       ) AS dT
--ORDER BY ?
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful. I posted the whole answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this Feel free to make any corrections. Thanks for helpful comments.

```
SELECT sid, sname
FROM ( SELECT sid, sname
       FROM student
       ORDER BY gpa DSC LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY gpa ASC LIMIT 1
```